# creating table in in cmd

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table reservation
(
   reservationid varchar2(6) primary key,
   userid varchar2(6) foreign key references userprofile(userid),
   vehicleid varchar2(6) foreign key references vehicle(vehicleid),
   routeid varchar2(8) foreign key references route(routeid),
   bookingdate date not null,
   journeydate date not null,
   driverid varchar2(6) foreign key references driver(driverid),
   bookingstatus varchar2(20) not null,
   totalfare number(10) not null,
   boardingpoint varchar2(30) not null,
   droppoint varchar2(30) not null,
   vname varchar2(20) not null 
);
```

I am getting an error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `foreign key` for an inline reference.  This code works in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0bc54):

```
create table vehicle (vehicleid varchar2(6) primary key);
create table userprofile (userid varchar2(6) primary key);
create table route (routeid varchar2(8) primary key);
create table driver (driverid varchar2(6) primary key);

create table reservation
(
   reservationid varchar2(6) primary key,
   userid varchar2(6) references userprofile(userid) ,
   vehicleid varchar2(6) references vehicle(vehicleid),
   routeid varchar2(8) references route(routeid),
   bookingdate date not null,
   journeydate date not null,
   driverid varchar2(6) references driver(driverid),
   bookingstatus varchar2(20) not null,
   totalfare number(10) not null,
   boardingpoint varchar2(30) not null,
   droppoint varchar2(30) not null,
   vname varchar2(20) not null 
);
```

Comment: thnx.........but still i am getting an error

Comment: SQL> create table reservation(reservationid varchar2(6) primary key,userid varch
ar2(6) references userprofile(userid),vehicleid varchar2(6) references vehicle(v
ehicleid),routeid varchar2(8) references route(routeid),bookingdate date not nul
l,journeydate date not null,driverid varchar2(6) references driver(driverid),boo
kingstatus varchar2(20) not null,totalfare number(10) not null,boardingpoint var
char2(30) not null,droppoint varchar2(30) not null,vname varchar2(20) not null);

Comment: *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: @faiyazsayeed . . . You need to declare the referenced tables correctly, with the right primary keys.